# What book has a magic forest behind a grandmother's house?

Tags: story-identification

I remember once I read a book in the library, and now I want to re-read it. I don't know the name though, however, it was such an entertaining read I can remember the story.

- 2 Children (1 boy 1 girl), mum and dad were going to take them somewhere as a surprise but logs fall on their car and kill their parents
- Then they go to their grandmother's house with a weird forest behind it that they shouldn't go in.
- They go in anyway

Now I can only remember some events that happened during the story after that point.

- The boy gets turned into a rabbit and cyclops were going to turn him into a casserole. The cyclops were sharing one eye between all 3 of them.
- Towards the end of the book the girl gets turned into a bird and the boy gets turned into a mouse and then the strange magic guy was going to kill the mouse by shutting a book on it.

I can't really remember anything else.

Comment: Was this a fairy tale or a fantasy novel, young-adult fantasy or adult fantasy or what?

Comment: @Richard I presume a children's novel, but, we all enjoy children's books?!

Comment: The sharing one eye thing is definitely used elsewhere but I can't remember where. But it's used by blind women who are like the three fates.

Comment: @ToddWilcox It's used exactly by the Fates in Percy Jackson and the Sea of Monsters (at the beginning, when they take the taxi to get to the camp). I don't know if it comes from mythology or if Riordan invented it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeae.

Comment: @ToddWilcox that's a common trope going back to ancient Greek legend and the Grey Sisters, though it's usually 3 "witches" or "fates" and not cyclops...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is "[Shadow Forest](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2032283.Shadow_Forest)" (Also published as "[Samuel Blink and the Forbidden Forest](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/974778.Samuel_Blink_and_the_Forbidden_Forest)").

> Samuel Blink is the hero of this story, but he doesn’t know it yet.
>   Right now, he and his sister Martha are in the back of his parents
>   car. He has no idea a giant log is about to fall from the sky and
>   change his life forever. He doesn’t know that he and Martha will be
>   forced to move to Norway and eat their Aunt Eda’s smelly brown cheese.
>   He hasn’t the slightest clue Martha will disappear into Shadow Forest.
>   A forest full of one-eyed trolls, the sinister huldre-folk, deadly
>   Truth Pixies and a witch who steals shadows. A forest ruled by the
>   evil Changemaker. A forest so dangerous that people who enter never
>   return.

[image]